# Load multiple components to js file but use only the required one(s)

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm learning to use the svelte framework to make components. But I haven't been able to make an instance of only one component from those I have loaded into the js file.

So, this is my html file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
     </head>
     <body>
<script src="./build/ReviewPanelComponent.js"></script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

My js input file (where I import the components):

```
import ReviewPanel from './ReviewPanel.html';

 const reviewPanel = new ReviewPanel({
      target: document.querySelector( 'body' ),
      data: 
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('rooms'))

    });

      export default {
        components: {
            reviewPanel,
        }
    }
```

And the html for the component:

```
<style>
#main{
    background-color:white;
}
h3,
h4,
h5{
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="main" class="col-xs-12">
            <div id="title">
                {{#if BookedRooms.length > 0}}
                    {{#each BookedRooms as br}}
                    <h3>{{br.Title}}</h3>
                        {{#each br.PossibleRateTypes as prt}}
                    <h4>{{prt.UUID}}</h4>

                        {{/each}}
                    {{/each}}
                {{/if}}             
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, at this moment, it loads the component, because it has an instance on the js input file. The thing is, at this moment, if I want a second instance I have to create one of the js file itself. I was thinking more like just importing all the components I want in the js file and in the html file where I want to use them I would just call them.

Is this possible. I've been reading the docs but I haven't found what I want.

EDIT: I forgot to say that I'm using webpack, also. Hence the input and output files. I managed to use multiple components. The solution I've found was to just do this on my js input file:

```
import ReviewPanel from './ReviewPanel.html';

 window.ReviewPanel=ReviewPanel;
 window.ReviewPanel2=ReviewPanel;
```

I put the imported object in a global variable so I can call it where I want it, like so:

```
<div id="reviewPanel"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Creates the review panel component
    window.ReviewPanel = new ReviewPanel({
        target: document.querySelector('#reviewPanel'),
        data:
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('rooms'))

    });
</script>
```

Yet, although I have this solution, my expectation would be import it only once in the js input file, without having to rely on global objects, and then just call it where I need it like so:

```
// And passing the parameters
<ReviewPanel />
```

Although I haven't seen much on React.js that's how I generally see programmers doing this. I was expecting the same. Still, as I have other things that need to be done, I'll leave it like this for now, to be optimized later.

Still, if anyone knows how to do this I'm all ears, as I'm new to Svelte and there's not much info on it, apart from the docs, which I consider a bit confusing on same parts.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, to achieve your goal you could use a [module bundler](https://medium.com/@gimenete/how-javascript-bundlers-work-1fc0d0caf2da) such as [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) with their respective Svelte [plugin](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-svelte) and [loader](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-loader). In this perspective, the easiest way to start is to use a template based on [one](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) or [the other](https://github.com/sveltejs/template-webpack).

Comment: Hence, what you are looking for are [dynamic components](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte.technology/blob/fa6e83ad4b7054265efa49bd5cf3d51a30c5078b/content/guide/06-special-components.md#component-tags). They have been recently added/documented.

Comment: Moreover dynamic components could be combined with [dynamic imports](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/test/parser/samples/dynamic-import/input.html) but I haven't tried to work with both things yet.